# Using readline keyboard shortcuts in OSX korn shell

Tags: macos, ksh, readline

I am using ksh on Mac OS X 10.6 xterm (that is, not using Terminal.app).

When I try to browse the command history via CTRL+P or try to move the cursor on my prompt via CTRL+B, only the characters ^P or ^B respectively are shown. 
Do I have to set some special environment variables or use some inputrc magic to trigger the expected effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ksh` on OSX is actual `ksh`, not `bash`.  This means that (a) it doesn't use `~/.inputrc` and (b) you need to turn on line editing explicitly with `set -o emacs` or `set -o gmacs`, or arrange for `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` environment variables to have a value that ends with `macs` so `ksh` will turn on Emacs-style line editiing automatically.  Since `$EDITOR` is not especially useful in an age of GUIs, adding `test -t 0 && set -o emacs` to `~/.kshrc` is probably the way to go.